# Using require would these result in the same object?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In `./foo.js`:

```
return {};
```

In `./bar.js`:

```
var o1 = require('./foo');
var o2 = require('./foo');
console.log(o1 === o2); // true or false?
```

Comment: Why didn't you test this then ask why if the answer confused you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module can be thought of like a singleton, so `o1 === o2` will be `true`.

Here is link to the wikipedia entry about the module pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_pattern